# Создание формы в MVS 2015 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winforms

Как к Visual Studio Community 2015 добавить форму для С++ проекта?
Создаю пустой проект, в добавлении элемента нет раздела UI

Comment: В C++ нет форм. То, что вы имеете в виду — C++/CLI, ужасный язык, который почему-то используется студентами для написания UI к лабораторным. Мой совет: если нужен UI, пишите на C#/WPF ну или WinForms. Если очень-очень нужно C++/CLI (это **не** C++), создайте проект типа WinForms под C++/CLI.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32404584/276994

Comment: Будущее за Borland C++ Builder

Comment: @tCode не дай Бог!

Comment: @VladD а чем ужасен C++/CLI ?

Comment: @Арина это гремучая смесь .NET и C++, которую используют для очень специфичных вещей на стыке нативного мира и .NET . Как уже было сказано, это не С++. Если вам все равно, то посмотрите на Qt с плагином Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сам по себе C++ не умеет в окна из коробки.

- [Вот так](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ff381409(v=vs.85).aspx) можно сделать окна с помощью **Windows API**
- [Вот так](http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.3.2/tutorial-t1.html) - с помощью фреймворка **Qt**.
- [Вот так](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_helloworld.html) - с помощью библиотеки **wxWidgets**
- [Вот так](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-helloworld.html.en) - с помощью **GTKmm**